# Flutter: How to compress network image

Tags: image, flutter, dart, caching, image-compression

I want to implement image compress with `cached_network_image` but I don't know how to manage both of them at a same time. How do I build my own compressed network image widget in flutter?

Comment: What do you mean with compressed network image ?

Comment: I want to compress the cached network image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do the same with `cached_network_image` as they've added some properties to manage the caching of images at the disk or memory level.

The properties are:

- cacheManager → BaseCacheManager?

Option to use cache manager with other settings

- maxHeightDiskCache → int?

Will resize the image and store the resized image in the disk cache.

- maxWidthDiskCache → int?

Will resize the image and store the resized image in the disk cache.

- memCacheHeight → int?

Will resize the image in memory to have a certain height using ResizeImage

- memCacheWidth → int?

Will resize the image in memory to have a certain width using ResizeImage

> As mentioned in API documentation https://pub.dev/documentation/cached_network_image/latest/cached_network_image/CachedNetworkImage-class.html

Other than these we've `height` and `width` constraints!

Answer (score 0):

To compress image you can use `flutter_image_compress` library which have common params like `minWidth` and `minHeight` which scales image as per value.

More params are:

- rotate: If you need to rotate the picture.
- quality: Quality of target image.
- format: Supports jpeg or png, default is jpeg.

To get more idea refer [This](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress).

Comment: you don't get the question, I want to manage network images at caching level